# Filter django queryset over a concatenated extra field

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have the following (shortened) Django-models:

```
class File(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    directory = models.ForeignKey(Directory)

class Directory(models.Model):
    path = models.TextField()
```

The user normally has the files displayed to him as `path + '/' + name`, f.e. `'/bin' + '/' + 'bash' => '/bin/bash'`. I am no trying to provide a search field to look for files.

If i work with Q()-Objects I can search for matches in either path or name, but it will fail if the user searches for `'/bin/bash'`.

So far I've come up with:

```
files = File.objects.extra(select={'fullpath': 'path || "/" || name'},
    tables=['directories'], order_by= ['fullpath']).distinct()
```

Unfortunately this does some sort of joining ALL directories with ALL filenames first, not only the ones that actually exist. Further, I cannot add another filter

```
.filter(fullpath__icontains=query)
```

Because I cannot reference the extra-field.

If at all possible, I'd want to stay with the django OR-Mapper and not perform raw SQL on the db.

Thanks for all suggestions

Answer (score 2):

You may use DB function **concat** in extra as i have done this to concat date in my case.

```
Event.objects.all().order_by('-start_time').extra(select={'date':'concat(year(start_time),\"/\",month(start_time),\"/\",day(start_time))','time':'concat(hour(start_time),\":\",minute(start_time))','program_no':'program_id'}).values('id','program_no','event_type__name','venue__city','venue__state','venue__website','series_id','date','time')
```

Hope this will help you.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The project for which this question was asked is now done and shipped; I no longer have access to the code or need to change it. I will keep it in mind though, if I should ever have that problem again.